# Inverse Gnomonic Projections of Plane

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, geometry

I have a spin-2 field namely the shape distortion of galaxies with:

```
γ=γ1+iγ2=|γ|exp(−2iϕ)
```

where `ϕ` is the orientation angle.

If this quantity has been measured on the sky coordinate which is a spherical coordinate assuming the centre of the measurement with `(α0 ,δ0)` as a zenithal point and the other point that this quantity would be measure with respect to center with `(α ,δ)` sky coordinate. How can I measure the `tangential` and `cross` components of γ using [gnomonic projection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GnomonicProjection.html) from spherical to Cartesian coordinates and illustrate it with `healpy` or `matplotlib`, while there is similar feature in [mathematica](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/InverseGnomonicProjectionsOfPlaneRegions/)?

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at matplotlib toolkit called [basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/)

and the its examples on [gnomonic projection](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/gnomon.html) and [coordinate conversion](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapcoords.html)

Once you create the Basemap object, called `m` in the example, you can transform
`latitude,longitude` coordinates to map coordinates doing

```
x, y = m(latitude, longitude)
```

and you can do the inverse tranform as

```
latitude, longitude = m(x, y, inverse=True)
```